# Rails joins + includes of same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

In a project at work I see a lot of code like

```
SomeModel.includes(:comments).joins(:comments).[...] # many more where and order clauses, other stuff
```

My question is: Does it make any sense to use `includes` and `joins` on the same table like `:comments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may make sense. These two methods serve different purposes. You need `joins` if you want to filter Posts by attributes of their Comments. And you need `includes` to avoid N+1 queries when rendering posts with comments.

Comment: Thanks! :) I realize now that it might also be possible to do this via SomeModel.includes(:comments).references(:comments), right?

Comment: @PeterSlotko: sounds like it: https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/4ybybl/rails_5_activerecord_includes_joins_and/

Comment: Very helpful link! Thanks! :)